# django plugin system - Extend root urlpatterns with installed app urlpatterns

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on a small plugin system using the existing Django features. I have managed to install plugins/apps based on the tenant(Multi-tenant model).

The problem I'm currently facing is that I want the plugins to have the option to add additional URLs, which works when directly added to the `urls.py` file. But this won't help me because the plugins will reside in the respective tenant directories.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could suggest how can we update/add more URLs to the current root URL.

Please find the relevant codes below:

```py
raw_plugin_url_patterns = []
 for app in apps.get_app_configs():
     if hasattr(app, 'PluginMeta'):
         if importlib.util.find_spec(app.name + '.urls'):
             urlmod = importlib.import_module(app.name + '.urls')
             if hasattr(urlmod, 'urlpatterns'):
                 raw_plugin_url_patterns.append(
                     path('%s' % app.label, include((urlmod.urlpatterns, app.label)))
                 )

PLUGIN_URL_PATTERS = []

 if raw_plugin_url_patterns:
     PLUGIN_URL_PATTERS = [path('plugins/', include((raw_plugin_url_patterns, 'plugins')))]
```

We can update the URL config, which I'm anyway doing for other logic in a middleware.

```py
        public_schema_name = get_public_schema_name()
        if has_multi_type_tenants():
            tenant_types = get_tenant_types()
            if (not hasattr(request, 'tenant') or
                    ((request.tenant.schema_name == get_public_schema_name()) and
                     'URLCONF' in tenant_types[public_schema_name])):
                request.urlconf = get_public_schema_urlconf()
            else:
                tenant_type = request.tenant.get_tenant_type()
                request.urlconf = tenant_types[tenant_type]['URLCONF']

            path = request.get_full_path()
            if path.startswith('/api'):
                tenant_type = request.tenant.get_tenant_type()
                request.urlconf = tenant_types[tenant_type]['API_URLCONF']

            set_urlconf(request.urlconf)
```

If there were some options which will allow us to change the `urlpatterns` within the conf just like setting the URL config will solve my current use case.